# add custom column to laravel excel

Tags: php, excel, laravel, laravel-excel

I am using [maatwebsite/excel](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel), I want to know if it's possible to add custom column when I export my data as CSV or not?

## Explanation

I am successfully exporting my `products` data, but my products have other option which is not stored in my products table such as: `specification`.

my specifications are stored in 2 different tables named `specifications` where is parent like `CPU` and `subscpecifications` where child's are stored like: `Core i5`.

another table i am using to store child's id and products id in order to relate each product to their subspecifications.

**Sounds Complecated right? :) `here i provide ugly map to get the logic` :)**

[image: screen 1]

#### Now, What I try to do is:

Add extra column to my csv file and include all specifications of each product.

sample:

[image: sample]

## Codes

here is my current export function

```
public function export(Request $request) {
      $input = $request->except('_token');
      foreach ($input['cb'] as $key => $value) {
        if ($value== 'on') {
          $getRealInput[$key] = $input['defaultname'][$key];
        }
      }

      $products = Product::select($getRealInput)->get();


      Excel::create('products', function($excel) use($products, $request) {
        $excel->sheet('sheet 1', function($sheet) use($products, $request){

          $input = $request->except('_token');
          foreach ($input['cb'] as $key => $value) {
            if ($value== 'on') {
              $getCustomInput[$key] = $input['customname'][$key];
            }
          }

          $sheet->fromArray($products, null, 'A1', false, false);
          $sheet->row(1, $getCustomInput);
        });
      })->export('csv');
      return redirect()->back();
    }
```

## Questions

1. Is that possible?
2. *If yes,* Base on my function above, how do I do it?

Thanks in advance.

## UPDATE 1

I have added this code to my function

```
$allRows = array();
  $data = array();
  foreach($products as $product){
  $specs = $product->subspecifications;
  foreach($specs as $spec){
    $data[] = $spec->specification->title;
    $data[] = $spec->title;
  }
}
array_push($allRows , $data);
```

and changed this line:

```
$sheet->fromArray($products, null, 'A1', false, false);
```

to

```
$sheet->fromArray($allRows, null, 'A1', false, false);
```

now here is what I have:

[image: screen3]

here is my full function currently:

```
public function export(Request $request) {
      $input = $request->except('_token');
      foreach ($input['cb'] as $key => $value) {
        if ($value== 'on') {
          $getRealInput[$key] = $input['defaultname'][$key];
        }
      }

      $products = Product::select($getRealInput)->get();


      Excel::create('products', function($excel) use($products, $request) {
        $excel->sheet('sheet 1', function($sheet) use($products, $request){

          $input = $request->except('_token');
          foreach ($input['cb'] as $key => $value) {
            if ($value== 'on') {
              $getCustomInput[$key] = $input['customname'][$key];
            }
          }


          // test code of adding subspacifications
          $allRows = array();
          $data = array();
          foreach($products as $product){
              $specs = $product->subspecifications;
              foreach($specs as $spec){
                    $data[] = $spec->specification->title;
                    $data[] = $spec->title;
              }
          }
          array_push($allRows , $data);
          $sheet->fromArray($allRows, null, 'A1', false, false);
          //
          // $sheet->fromArray($products, null, 'A1', false, false);
          $sheet->row(1, $getCustomInput);
        });
      })->export('csv');
      return redirect()->back();
    }
```

## UPDATE 2

Well tonight I've played with my codes a lot and FINALLY :) I got what I needed, here is how:

```
//codes...

// Here is you custom columnn logic goes
          foreach($products as $product){
            $specifications = DB::table('products')
            ->where('products.id', $product->id)
            ->join('product_subspecification', 'product_subspecification.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
            ->join('subspecifications', 'subspecifications.id', '=', 'product_subspecification.subspecification_id')
            ->select('subspecifications.title')
            ->pluck('title');

            $product['specifications'] = rtrim($specifications,',');
          }
          //


          $sheet->fromArray($products, null, 'A1', false, false);
          $sheet->row(1, $getCustomInput);

//... rest of the codes
```

This will give me my products specifications, however there is 3 little issues:

1. I do not have heading for my specifications in CSV file
2. Products without specification shows `[]` instead of nothing
3. products with specification also covers them with `[]` and `""`

Here I provided screenshot for better understanding:

[image: screen5]

Comment: It should be possible. So you have your specification relationships setup, what column from the specifications did you want to use in the column?

Comment: @CUGreen title column.

Comment: anyone with knowledge? :/

Comment: can anyone help in answering this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50036491/impossible-4-columns-permutation-with-limit-of-11-in-vba-excel

Answer (score 3):

You need to prepare custom column **Specifications** by looping through products. Here is your fix,

```
public function export(Request $request) {

  $headers[] = [
                'Id',
                'Title',
                'Specifications',
            ];


  $input = $request->except('_token');
  foreach ($input['cb'] as $key => $value) {
    if ($value== 'on') {
      $getRealInput[$key] = $input['defaultname'][$key];
    }
  }

  $products = Product::select($getRealInput)->with('subspecifications')->get()->toArray();

  Excel::create('products', function($excel) use($headers,$products, $request) {
    $excel->sheet('sheet 1', function($sheet) use($headers,$products, $request){

      $input = $request->except('_token');
      foreach ($input['cb'] as $key => $value) {
        if ($value== 'on') {
          $getCustomInput[$key] = $input['customname'][$key];
        }
      }
      // Here is you custom columnn logic goes
          foreach($products as $product){
            $specs = "";
            $specifications = DB::table('products')
            ->where('products.id', $product->id)
            ->join('product_subspecification', 'product_subspecification.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
            ->join('subspecifications', 'subspecifications.id', '=', 'product_subspecification.subspecification_id')
            ->select('subspecifications.title')
            ->pluck('title');
            foreach($specifications as $spec){
              $specs = $specs .','.$spec;
            }
            $product['specifications'] = ltrim($specs,',');
          }
          //
      $mergedProducts = array_merge($headers, $products);
      $sheet->fromArray($mergedProducts, null, 'A1', false, false);
      $sheet->row(1, $getCustomInput);
    });
  })->export('csv');
  return redirect()->back();
}
```

**Update**

As per your sheet image I can assume you have only three columns Id, Title and Specifications, you can change header array according to the columns you are getting from DB.

Comment: i get `Undefined offset: 0` on `$sheet->fromArray($products, null, 'A1', false, false);`

Comment: Can you please dd($products) ?

Comment: i assume `specifications` must add to each product and not end of my collection  right?

Comment: I have updated the code above please run now and let me know.

Comment: `preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given`

Comment: OK, I took some screenshots for you to see what exactly happened: `1`  https://ibb.co/daZ4KH `2` 
https://ibb.co/cwDyeH

Comment: still getting `preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given`

Comment: bro are you there? any idea?

Comment: can you please do `echo "<pre>";  print_r($products); ` so that I can understand better ?

Comment: in which part i add that `pre` ?

Comment: before this line  `$sheet->fromArray($products, null, 'A1', false, false);` add the above statements.

Comment: the result become so messy! something between white page and laravel black error page, really can't get anything out of it.

Comment: ok bro i just acted fast before my view broke i got copy the codes here i shared php file including what i could copy from your `pre` code   https://ufile.io/oyq42

Comment: Bro I got my specifications, please see my update. thanks.

Comment: Updated answer please try now.

Comment: hi bro, o answer your update i have to say: `no, i have more than id,title,specification (i can have all my table columns)` so i really can't use `header` part and `$mergedProducts = array_merge($headers, $products);` you provided, But except headers and `merge` part, your function works perfectly `just no have heading` https://ibb.co/i3amOc

Comment: what if, we use their parents as heading? currently we are getting `subspecifications` like `core i7` what if we get `specifications` as heading like `cpu (as heading)` and `core i7 (as data of it)` ?

Comment: Then you have to define all you db columns in header plus custom specifications column at the last.

Comment: i do have all my columns as header i just have ability to filter them so i can only get id and title or all of them, but for specification matter if you see my first update (no.1) in there i have both specifications and subspecifications in header that time i did it like `foreach($specs as $spec){
    $data[] = $spec->specification->title;
    $data[] = $spec->title;
  }` now we need the same approach but different `$data_name` for sub and specs to define which one goes where.

Comment: Disucssing is getting long, your main issue is solved, closed it and start another one if you have other queries thanks

Comment: is the same query bro "need header for results i'm getting", if you no longer able to help i understand and appreciate all your helps

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible.
create array for row ie. `data = array();`
push cell data to array

you can fetch relation data using eloquent or join as well, here I am fetching inside loop.

Updated Function as below:

I tried to match with your data structure

```
  public function export(Request $request) {
  $input = $request->except('_token');
  foreach ($input['cb'] as $key => $value) {
    if ($value== 'on') {
      $getRealInput[$key] = $input['defaultname'][$key];
    }
  }

  $products = Product::select($getRealInput)->get();


  Excel::create('products', function($excel) use($products, $request) {
    $excel->sheet('sheet 1', function($sheet) use($products, $request){


      // test code of adding subspacifications
      $allRows = array();
      array_push($allRows , ['id', 'title', 'specifications']); // Added title row
      $data = array();
      foreach($products as $product){
          $data[] = $product->id;    // Added product fields 
          $data[] = $product->title;
          $specs = $product->subspecifications;
          $spec_details = "";
          foreach($specs as $spec){                    
                $spec_details .= $spec->specification->title.':'. $spec->title. ' '; // appended specification:subspecification 
          }
          $data[] = $spec_details;
      }
      array_push($allRows , $data);
      $sheet->fromArray($allRows, null, 'A1', false, false);
      //
      // $sheet->fromArray($products, null, 'A1', false, false);
      //$sheet->row(1, $getCustomInput);   // commented
    });
  })->export('csv');
  return redirect()->back();
}
```

Comment: sorry for very late answer bro, but this doesn't works. there is some issues in you code that concern me: `1` where is this coming from? `$allRows = array();` . `2` my products are already looped i don't need to use this `foreach($products as $product)`, `3` this does not provide true relation `$specs = Spec::where('product_id', $product->id)->get();`

Comment: I have shared update in my question please check it.   `PS` for this part i still have problem `$data[] = $product->field1;` as my columns coming by selection `$getCustomInput[$key] = $input['customname'][$key];` i cannot use static method as you shared in your answer is there other way to achieve that? as you see my csv is empty because of that. THANK YOU.

Comment: thanks bro, here is issues with your method: `1` as i said before, i cannot have my products table data statically like `$data[] = product->id;` why? because i'm using filter on my columns by `foreach ($input['cb'] as $key => $value) {` that's why i have `$sheet->row(1, $getCustomInput);`.  `2` your recent code shows all products in row 2 except shows each product detail in one row `3` i get `:` between tags except `,` .

Answer (score 0):

1. I do not have heading for my specifications in CSV file

To solve the issue, you can define header and use use `array_merge()`. For I.E.

```
$headers[] = [
                'Title',
                'Specifications',
            ];
$products= array_merge($headers, $products);
```

2. Products without specification shows [] instead of nothing
3. products with specification also covers them with [] and ""

For 2nd and 3rd point you can use `implode()` to get rid of `[]`

```
$product['specifications'] = implode(',', $specifications);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks for answer, those problems are solved, the only last issue is my specifications header and why your answer won't work here i explained it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49809945/add-custom-column-to-laravel-excel/49939862#comment87052010_49939862 please see if you can help with that.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. very simple

```
// Headings//
$headers[] = ['Id', 'Name'];

// 2 Rows //
$data[0] = ['1', 'John'];
$data[1] = ['2', 'Roger'];

Excel::create('report', function($excel) use($headers, $data) {

    $excel->sheet('sheet 1', function($sheet) use($headers, $data){
        $merged_records = array_merge($headers, $data);
        $sheet->fromArray($merged_records, null, 'A1', false, false);
    });
})->export('csv');
```